# Is main.cpp required?

Tags: c++, syntax, program-entry-point

I was trying to compile a program with `cmake`, and I ended up deleting my `main.cpp` file, which I had just compounded into another file which held the name of my project (i.e., I just cut and pasted the main function into that one). The problem is that I got a `main.cpp` not found error, and wasn't sure whether or not in `C++` a file known as `main.cpp` is required, or can I have a file with a different title which contains the function main instead?

**Edit**
I should note that I *have* removed any specification to `main` and have recompiled this program.

Comment: What does your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like?  Does it specifically mention `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you don't need a file named main.cpp.  You don't need a file containing main() unless you are building an application.  That is, if you were just building a library of functions or a standalone object file you would not require main().

Answer (score 5):

Name of the source file has nothing to do for a program successful build. All you need a source file that has main function. How ever, naming the file as `main.cpp` is just a programming practice to just easily locate where the main function is.

Answer (score 1):

No the main method doesn't have to be in a file called `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any file name you want, you just need to update it in the makefile